# Optimizing mariabb/mysql queries as a DBA

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mariadb

I'm maintaining a database that's used by a bespoke software application that has some performance issues. On of the worst offenders is query (3) below, and I'd like to, if possible, optimize the execution plan from the database side, since asking the developers to change anything tends to be costly and take quite a while.

(1) This query is fast, using indexes:

```
explain
select game.id from games.game where home = 573368 and active = 1
union
select game.id from games.game where guest=573368 and active = 1
union
select game.id from games.game, games.gamegroup where gamegroup.game=game.id and gamegroup.team=573368 and active=1;
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type  | table        | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra       |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | game         | ref    | active,home    | home    | 5       | const                |   10 | Using where |
|    2 | UNION        | game         | ref    | active,guest   | guest   | 5       | const                |   10 | Using where |
|    3 | UNION        | gamegroup    | ref    | game,team      | team    | 5       | const                |    1 | Using where |
|    3 | UNION        | game         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,active | PRIMARY | 4       | games.gamegroup.game |    1 | Using where |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3> | ALL    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | NULL |             |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
```

(2) Taking the results of this into a second query is fast as well:

```
explain
select * from games.game where id in (3661383, 3661488, 3661543, 3661598, 3661668, 3661718, 3661743, 3661808, 3661868, 3661893, 3661393, 3661443, 3661483, 3661483, 3661533, 3661578, 3661623, 3661658, 3661763, 3661818, 3661878);
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | game  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   20 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

(3) However, plugging the first query into the second as a subselect results in a full table scan (FTS) and is accordingly slow:

```
explain
select * from games.game where id in (
    select game.id from games.game where home = 573368 and active = 1
    union
    select game.id from games.game where guest=573368 and active = 1
    union
    select game.id from games.game, games.gamegroup where gamegroup.game=game.id and gamegroup.team=573368 and active=1
);
+------+--------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type        | table        | type   | possible_keys        | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+------+--------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | game         | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 917603 | Using where |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | game         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,active,home  | PRIMARY | 4       | func  |      1 | Using where |
|    3 | DEPENDENT UNION    | game         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,active,guest | PRIMARY | 4       | func  |      1 | Using where |
|    4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | gamegroup    | ref    | game,team            | team    | 5       | const |      1 |             |
|    4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | game         | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY | 4       | func  |      1 | Using where |
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union2,3,4> | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |   NULL |             |
+------+--------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

(4) Nesting another subselect which does effectively nothing except giving the thing a name avoids the FTS, making the query fast again:

```
explain
select * from games.game where id in (
    select  * from (
        select game.id from games.game where home = 573368 and active = 1
        union
        select game.id from games.game where guest=573368 and active = 1
        union
        select game.id from games.game, games.gamegroup where gamegroup.game=game.id and gamegroup.team=573368 and active=1
    ) as uni
);
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type  | table        | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra       |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>  | ALL    | distinct_key   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |   21 |             |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | game         | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | uni.id               |    1 |             |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | <derived3>   | ALL    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |   21 |             |
|    3 | DERIVED      | game         | ref    | active,home    | home    | 5       | const                |   10 | Using where |
|    4 | UNION        | game         | ref    | active,guest   | guest   | 5       | const                |   10 | Using where |
|    5 | UNION        | gamegroup    | ref    | game,team      | team    | 5       | const                |    1 | Using where |
|    5 | UNION        | game         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,active | PRIMARY | 4       | games.gamegroup.game |    1 | Using where |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union3,4,5> | ALL    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | NULL |             |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
```

Unfortunately, the application, which isn't easy to get changed, uses query (3).

Are there any steps that can be taken from the DBA side to nudge the execution plan of (3) into the direction of (4)?

I did read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html, which needs the application to pass hints through, and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html, which seems to affect all queries on a global basis. However, I'd like to give the DB a hint just for this query. Is there any way, in mysql/mariadb, to do that? Or is there another workaround?

---

As requested in a comment, here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `no` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `class` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gdate` char(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sgdate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gtime` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gymnasium` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ogymnasium` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oresp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guest` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hgoals` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ggoals` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hgoals1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ggoals1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hpoints` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpoints` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `period` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `comment` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mdt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disposer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disposer_org` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms2check` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `req` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reqtype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupsort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `round` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `editstatus` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `ti_err` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refereeinfo_a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refereeinfo_b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_a_adrnr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_b_adrnr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_org` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `ref_costs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_sealed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sealed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `gdate` (`gdate`),
  KEY `class` (`class`),
  KEY `period` (`period`),
  KEY `sgdate` (`sgdate`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `dt` (`dt`),
  KEY `admin` (`admin`),
  KEY `sms2check` (`sms2check`),
  KEY `gymnasium` (`gymnasium`),
  KEY `home` (`home`),
  KEY `guest` (`guest`),
  KEY `groupsort` (`groupsort`),
  KEY `resp` (`resp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3796577 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



CREATE TABLE `gamegroup` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game` (`game`),
  KEY `team` (`team`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46302 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Show `game` and `gamegroup` DDLs. I.e. the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` outputs.

Comment: What if, on the third query you change from `IN` to `INNER JOIN (*sub-query*) xx ON game.id=xx.id`? Will it be faster or slower?

Comment: @tcadidot0: That makes the query fast, resulting in an execution plan similar to (4).

Comment: And the results I assume also correct?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes they are. The problem is that this will still require me to have the software changed, which I'd like to avoid if possible. Except if there's some global parameter that tells mariadb to treat subselects as inner joins if possible, in the hope of not causing bad effects on other queries?

Comment: Ok, I think I saw that coming as I am also the same. I can work with how to maybe make a query quicker but when it comes to software change, I can't do anything. But if this change does make the operation much faster in the long run, also beneficial to many people, I think it's worth a software change - just my opinion ;) . Also, I'm not aware if mariadb have a function to treat subselects as inner join, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Add composite keys:**

```
games:  INDEX(home, active, id)
games:  INDEX(guest, active, id)
gamegroup:  INDEX(team, game)
```

**Shrink the data:**

`INT` always takes 4 bytes.  `TINYINT UNSIGNED` takes 1 bytes and is probably more than adequate for `period`, `active` etc.

If `gamegroup` is a **many-to-many** mapping between teams and games, you probably don't need `id`.  Instead:

```
CREATE TABLE `gamegroup` (
  `game` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (team, game),
  KEY         (game, team)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46302 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Formulation 5:**

```
select g.*
    FROM (
        select game.id from games.game where home = 573368 and active = 1
        union
        select game.id from games.game where guest=573368 and active = 1
        union
        select game.id
            FROM games.game
            JOIN games.gamegroup
            where gamegroup.game = game.id
              and gamegroup.team=573368
              and active=1
         ) as uni
    JOIN game AS g  USING(id)
);
```

This effectively does '1', then '2'.

**`UNION ALL`** is usually faster than `UNION DISTINCT` (which is what `UNION` means).  But you can get dups.

**`IN ( SELECT ... )`** should be avoided -- there  are many cases (especially in older MySQL versions) where it performs terribly.

**More tips:**  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**Even better**  Provide a Stored Procedure that `573368` as an argument and delivers the result set using whatever is deemed the optimal formulation.  They will prefer doing `CALL` instead of typing all that lengthy query.  *That* may get them to change their code.